# Call onclick JS event on website button using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, onclick

I am using VBA to interact with a website in IE.

As part of this I need to click a button there but a simple `.Click` does not work as I need to **trigger the JS onclick event behind this button**.

Can someone here tell me how I can achieve this, either by simulating the click and triggering the event or by calling the JS event directly ?

This should happen after the below VBA code.

**My VBA code:**

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim MyURL As String
Dim varResults As New DataObject

varResults.SetText TxtSql.Text
varResults.PutInClipboard
Unload FrmResults

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

MyURL = "https://myFirstUrl"

IE.Navigate MyURL
IE.Visible = True

While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) ' to allow time for loading the page
```

**The onclick JS event behind the button:**

```
javascript:document.forms.jobProfileForm.action='https://mySecondUrl';document.forms.jobProfileForm.submit()
```

**The button's HTML:**

```
<input class="normalbttn" id="editProfileBttn" value="Edit Profile" onclick="theAboveJS" type="button"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`IE.Document.getelementbyid("editProfileBttn").fireevent ("onclick")`

Comment: Thanks, scott ! I tried this but no difference - it does not trigger the button / event and does not load the page with the textarea.